# How to remove Deprecated Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader?

Tags: php, symfony

I have upgrade Symfony 3.4 to 4.4. The only Deprecation warning left is this:

> php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader" class is deprecated
> since Symfony 4.4, use "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\DebugClassLoader" instead.
> {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated:
> The "Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4,
> use "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\DebugClassLoader" instead.
> at /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:16)"} []

I am not use `DebugClassLoader` anywhere. How do I remove this warning?

Comment: Consider creating a fresh 4.4 project and the comparing files such as index.php, Kernel.php and console with whatever you have.  These sorts of files are not updated as part of the usual upgrade process and eventually get out of sync.  And it will probably fix your issue.

Answer (score 33):

Check your `index.php` and your `bin/console` files.

In `index.php`, for example, there should be a part like this:

```php
if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}
```

But the corresponding import is likely to be:

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
```

In both files change it to:

```
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
```

Comment: I am on the latest SF 4.4 version locally and there are 5 different Symfony files still referencing this, albeit some as `LegacyDebugClassLoader`. The `maker-bundle` is one too.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `bin/console` file.

You need change:

> use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

to:

> use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;

When command is executed you will receive a deprecation message.

Answer (score -1):

If you check the trace, you will see:

```
User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\DebugClassLoader" instead.
Show context    Hide trace
{▼
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:16 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Caster/ExceptionCaster.php:216 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Caster/ExceptionCaster.php:149 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Cloner/AbstractCloner.php:341 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Cloner/VarCloner.php:209 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Cloner/AbstractCloner.php:274 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/DataCollector.php:85 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/LoggerDataCollector.php:75 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/Profiler.php:100 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ProfilerListener.php:127 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:126 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:264 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:239 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:168 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:103 {▶}
  /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:166 {▶}
  /var/www/html/web/app_dev.php:13 {▼
    › $response->send();
    › $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
    › 
  }
}
```

It seems to be coming from `Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel`.

Search the usage in vendor folder, if it comes from other component than Symfony, check maybe newer version of the component, has a fix for it. If the deprecated component is used by only Symfony itself, I would not spend too much time worrying about it. It will get resolved, once you upgrade your Symfony to the next major version.

Comment: As nobobdy mentioned that the error is coming from `bin/console`, what makes you think this is the case for the OP?

Comment: Also, as Jake posted that he just updated from 3.4 to 4.4, how does your answer relate to that?

Comment: @NicoHaase you are correct, I updated my answer removing bin/console note. As of 4.4 mark, it was deprecated in that version. It will get resolved by upgrading Symfony to next major version.